# Customize Google Charts Gauge Blue Circle

Tags: charts, google-visualization, gauge

I need to customize the blue circle from google charts gauge.  I see that google-charts builds a svg image.  Is there a way to change the color of the center cicle or the gauge's needle.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

there are no standard config options,
but you can manually change the svg,
on the chart's `'ready'` event

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['gauge']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Memory', 80],
    ['CPU', 55],
    ['Network', 68]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 400, height: 120,
    redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
    yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
    minorTicks: 5
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('circle'), function(circle) {
      if (circle.getAttribute('fill') === '#4684ee') {
        circle.setAttribute('fill', '#5e35b1');
      }
    });
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('path'), function(path) {
      if (path.getAttribute('stroke') === '#c63310') {
        path.setAttribute('stroke', '#00bcd4');
        path.setAttribute('fill', '#00bcd4');
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I`m using angular-google-charts, and you give me a great idea on how to customize the center circle.

Comment: WhiteHat - you knew the tag names of 'circle' and 'path'. Is there a document describing how to find the tag names that comprise the entire SVG? I am not aware how to dissect an AVG to find the tag names.

Comment: does this help? --> [SVG element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element)

Comment: In terms of using a reference like this, if I wanted to modify the color of the word that displays across the gauge, how could I use this reference to find that tag?

Comment: Is it just <text>?

Comment: I found it! It is if (text.textContent === 'xxx') { ...!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WhiteHat, I was able to change the default blue center circle.  I´m using angular-google-charts module, and using @WhiteHat idea, I customized the "uncustomizable" by configuration blue circle:

**HTML:**

```
              <google-chart             
              [type]="'Gauge'" 
              [data] ="gaugeSales" 
              [options]="gaugeOptions" 
              [dynamicResize]="'true'"
              (ready)="this.customizeGauge()"
              >
```

**TS**

```
customizeGauge()
{ 
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('circle'), function(circle) {
    if (circle.getAttribute('fill') === '#4684ee') {
      circle.setAttribute('fill', '#5e35b1');
    }
  });
}
```